# UIPickerView Swift - Multi linea

Tags: swift, xcode

Desde ya gracias a todos los que se tomen su tiempo

Tengo un UIPicker

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde me gustaria que pudiera tener el "AMIGO" - "NO AMIGO" por debajo de la primera linea

por ej :
item1

BRUNO GERMAN SOSA FERNANDEZ

AMIGO

item2

BRUNO GERMAN SOSA FERNANDEZ

NO AMIGO

Intente con

```
 var pickerLabel: UILabel? = (view as? UILabel)
                                
    if pickerLabel == nil {
        pickerLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: pickerView.frame.size.width , height: 60))
        pickerLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15.0)
        pickerLabel?.textAlignment = .center
        pickerLabel!.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        pickerLabel!.numberOfLines = 2
        
    }
```

Aunque si queda en 2 linea cuando el texto es realmente grande, me gustaria poder siempre cortar la segunda linea con las propiedades que yo quiera

Intente colocar 2 labels con subviews pero la misma no queda abajo sino que se suporponen,

Ando perdido si es posible, aunque no me parece nada loco, pero no encontre info al respecto

Answer (score 0):

En Swift puedes agregar una nueva linea usando la secuencia `\n`, pero si quieres una nueva linea y un retorno de carro (carriage return) debes usar `\r\n`, ejemplo:

```
var texto: String = "Hola\r\nBruno"
```

pero también puedes usar

```
let texto = """
         Hola
         Bruno
         """
```